# Laravel 8 - formatValidationErrors()

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel 5 there was a function `formatValidationErrors()` that allowed you to format error messages. The application I am updating to Laravel 8 used this to take the validator errors and flashed it to Session. Is there an equivalent for this in Laravel 8? I can't find in the docs.

```
protected function formatValidationErrors(Validator $validator)
    {
        if($validator->errors()->all()) {
            Session::flash('error', $validator->errors()->all()[0]);
        }
        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add custom validation error message like in [here](https://%20https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)
Or you can create your custom exception handler class like in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#the-exception-handler)

If your problem is app-wide then you can use handler class to format all your validations.